# Android Resources: How are bitmaps loaded from resources handled memory wise?

Tags: java, android, memory, imageview

When you load a bitmap from the resources like so:

```
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

1. if the bitmap is reduced in quality by Scaletype, does it still save the whole original bitmap? (I would guess yes, because one could change the Scaletype on the fly and you would want to have the full quality.)
2. if you load the same resources ID into multiple ImageView's, is there only one bitmap stored in memory?
3. would it be good practice to scan through the view hierarchy and manually recycle these bitmaps (by extracting the BitmapDrawable from the ImageView) in onDestroy or can I be sure that this is done in time by the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, It will keep full Quality.
2. No, It will maintain a single object.
3. It will be done by the System. No need to bother. But, It wait until some buffer got filled with the data for calling the GC. Once the buffer filled with unwanted data, then at a time the objects will be removed from the memory. If you still want, you can take care.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. I do find that I need to do manual GC's on some devices to prevent crashes. I'm still unsure whether this is just inherent to these devices or whether I'm doing something fundamentally wrong. I guess something for another SO post :-) Thanks